# Integrate NPS in an email and retrieve data

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, cloudpage, email-studio, survey

I would like to send a triggered email with NPS inside it.
As I understand it is not possible to integrate Javascript into an email.
The solution would then be to have 10 different images.
My question is, what is the best way to retrieve data?
Can I make one unique cloud pages which can recover the image clicked by the user?
And do I have to make 10 different cloud pages depending on the image clicked?
Or maybe there is other solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a parameter to the URL, e.g. `?nps=1` which differs between images. 
You will then just need a single Cloud Page, and use [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) function, to get the value from nps parameter.

Then it's up to you whether you want to differentiate content on the landing page accordingly, or just store the value.

Answer (score 0):

My company AskNicely has released a native NPS integration for Marketing Cloud. Check it out!

https://www.asknicely.com/blog/asknicely-nps-marketing-cloud

http://help.asknice.ly/integrations/marketing-cloud-trigger-asknicely-surveys-from-journey-builder

Might give you some ideas on how to trigger NPS along the customer journey (which is undoubtedly super valuable!)

Comment: please make sure to include the essentials of the links you posted so users dont necessarily have to leave the site. additionally, should the links become invalid, the answer will/shoudl remain valid. thanks